# Typescript, DDD: validations

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design

I've been researching a lot about input validations, and I was a little confused, many indicate leaving validations of type size, type of a particular variable in the domain, to perform the validation in a way that does not lead to leakage of domain knowledge
good and with that, as i'm using typescript i thought of a static function to create my aggregate and use a static function with the name of canBuild, to validate if it is possible to create the aggregate

like this:

```
export class PersonAggregrate extends Entity<IPersonProps> {
  private constructor(props: IPersonProps, id?: string) {
    super(props, id)
  }

  private static canBuild(props: IPersonJSON): IErrorModel[] {
    let errors = [] as IErrorModel[]
    if (typeof props.firstName !== 'string') errors.push({})
    if (typeof props.lastName !== 'string') errors.push({})
    if (props.firstName.length < 4) errors.push({})
    if (props.lastName.length < 2) errors.push({})
    return errors
  }

  public static build(
    props: IPersonJSON & { id?: string },
  ): Either<IErrorModel[], Person> {
    const hasErrs = this.canBuild(props)
    const user = User.build(props.user)
    if (user.isLeft()) {
      hasErrs.push(...user.value)
      return left(hasErrs)
    }
    if (hasErrs.length > 0) return left(hasErrs)
    const person = new Person({ ...props, user: user.value }, props.id)
    return right(person)
  }
}
```

user entity:

```
export class User extends Entity<IUserJSON> {
  private constructor(props: IUserJSON, id?: string) {
    super(props, id)
  }

  private static canBuild(user: IUserJSON) {
    let errors = [] as IErrorModel[]
    if (typeof user.login !== 'string') errors.push({})
    if (typeof user.password !== 'string') errors.push({})
    if (user.refreshToken && !validator.isJWT(user.refreshToken)) {
      errors.push({})
    }
    return errors
  }

  public static build(
    props: IUserJSON & { id?: string },
  ): Either<IErrorModel[], User> {
    const canBuild = this.canBuild(props)
    if (canBuild.length > 0) left(canBuild)
    const user = new User(props, props.id)
    return right(user)
  }
}
```

my user entity is part of my aggregrated person

Did I also do the following in my command to create an aggregrate:

```
export class CreatePersonCommand implements ICommand {
  private readonly id: string
  private readonly login!: string
  private readonly password!: string
  private readonly personId!: string
  private readonly firstName!: string
  private readonly lastName!: string

  constructor(person: Omit<IPersonJSON & IUserJSON, 'user' | 'personId'>) {
    this.id = v4()
    this.personId = this.id
    this.login = person.login
    this.password = person.password
    this.firstName = person.firstName
    this.lastName = person.lastName
  }

  public CanExecute(): boolean {
    let errors = [] as IErrorModel[]
    for (let field in this) {
      if (!this[field]){
        errors.push({ code: 215, message: `Required field: ${field}` })
      }
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) throw new BadRequestERROR({ errors })
    return errors.length <= 0
  }
}
```

to not allow data to be sent to the entity without the properties of the aggregate

```
export class CreatePersonCommand implements ICommand {
  private readonly id: string
  private readonly login!: string
  private readonly password!: string
  private readonly personId!: string
  private readonly firstName!: string
  private readonly lastName!: string

  constructor(person: Omit<IPersonJSON & IUserJSON, 'user' | 'personId'>) {
    this.id = v4()
    this.personId = this.id
    this.login = person.login
    this.password = person.password
    this.firstName = person.firstName
    this.lastName = person.lastName
  }

  public CanExecute(): boolean {
    let errors = [] as IErrorModel[]
    for (let field in this) {
      if (!this[field]){
        errors.push({ code: 215, message: `Required field: ${field}` })
      }
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) throw new BadRequestERROR({ errors })
    return errors.length <= 0
  }
}
```

in my aggregate, I do not use throw in errors because they are just input data errors, but I don't know if I should consider it (empty data as untreated input data, as they are not being sent)
and on my mediator I use canExecute before executing the command:

```
public publish<T extends ICommand>(command: T): Promise<any> {
    if (!command) throw new InvalidCommandException()
    const handler = this.registry.get(command.constructor.name)
    if (!handler) throw new HandlerNotFoundException(command.constructor.name)
    if(!command.CanExecute()) throw new InvalidCommandException()
    return handler.execute(command)
  }
```

I would like to know is this correct or is there a better option?

Comment: I think you may find [this blog post](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/always-valid-domain-model/) very helpful.

Comment: @plalx hey bro thank you very much this clarified a lot, i was following the same path, but mistakenly, do you want to create an answer for me to give a positive vote?

Comment: this helpme alot about my questions, thank u .

Comment: I invite you to answer your own question with the knowledge you gained ;) I'm glad it was helpful! It's definitely one of the best posts I've read about validation.